# using stomp function in golang

Tags: go, websocket, stomp

I am trying to establish a stomp connection using stomp.dial() function at the client side, but unable to connect to the server.

I am using go-stomp library. I tried different methods like using net.connect and then stomp.connect, but its resulting in the same error. the error goes like
read tcp: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
What is exactly happening here and how to resolve it
My code looks something like

```
ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 5)
    defer ticker.Stop()
    for ; ; <-ticker.C {
        st, err := stomp.Dial("tcp", conn.ConfigStr)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Stomp connect error", err.Error())
            continue
        }
                log.Println("CONNECTED TO ", conn.ProviderName)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish your request in this way.
First I run a STOMP server locally on port `61613`. To launch it, I used this command:
`docker run -it --rm -p 61613:61613 efrecon/stomp -verbose 5`
Then, I used the package `go-stomp` together with the function `Dial` to connect to it:

```golang
package main

import "github.com/go-stomp/stomp/v3"

func main() {
    conn, err := stomp.Dial("tcp", "localhost:61613")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer func() {
        if err = conn.Disconnect(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()
}
```

Lastly, I used the `Disconnect` method to close the connection.
Let me know if this works also for you.

Comment: I am getting this error when I run the above command to launch - docker: error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Post "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/create": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. @Ivan

Comment: Do you have Docker installed and running on your machine?
Otherwise, you can download from here https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/

Comment: I have docker on my machine

Comment: If you run this `systemctl is-active docker` what is the output? Or try a simple `docker ps -a`

Comment: when I run `docker ps -a` I am getting- error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json?all=1": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: You can follow this guide to make sure that your Docker service is running
https://linuxhint.com/resolve-docker-daemon-not-running/
In the end, you should be able to run successfully the above-written command. You can test with this command `docker run hello-world` which should give you a welcome messge.